# What SQL Server version or platform is EngineEdition "SQL Database" in SERVERPROPERTY

Tags: .net, sql-server, cloud

What version or platform is "SQL Database" (value 5) in `SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')`.  [The Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't offer a description of it.

Comment: *Most likely* it refers [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/)

Comment: I wonder why they didn't mention "Azure" in the name as they do with the other Azure editions shown in the docs.